# What is ruby equivalent to dll / shared reusable code library?

Tags: ruby

I"m looking to centralize common code from two projects in Ruby (Not rails)
Couldn't find straight answer.

Thanks alot

Comment: [Make yourself a gem](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ruby gem, or a module that you can copy to different projects, but the gem makes more sense.

Comment: Adding this link (or similar) may help the OP? http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/